# Express application for Authentication as seperate microservice

Tags: node.js, docker, express, get, passport.js

**Current Situation:**

I am currently working with a specific oauth provider and i am hosting my applications as microservices in a kubernetes cluster.

My end user is actively working with an angular application hosted as a docker container using nginx as webserver.

Now my idea was to integrate the authentication as a seperate microservice using node.js express and passport. so The workflow would be

User hits login in angular and gets redirected to the express application (same host address just a different endpoint /auth/someProvider)

The express application has no user interface it just handles all the oauth redirecting and communication with the provider, after the user information has been collected it redirects back to the angular application.

Now this works pretty for one last part. When my /auth/provider/callback would redirect inside of the express application it is very easy to access the request object that has been extended with the user object. when I redirect to an external website I get the cookie and everything but not an easy way to access the user object.

**My acutal question(s):**

Is there a safe way to pass that user information from the Request object directly to be used by the angular application (Best way i could think of is to use the headers as they are encrypted as well in https but still seems kind of hacky).

Is ita good idea in general to use OAuth that way.

The big advantage to this solution would be that I could use the same Docker Container with many web projects not having to implement Authentication one by one by just changing ClientId and Secret Env Vars in that Docker Container.

Answer (score 0):

OK this is how I made it work.

basically you implement the basic concept described in the passport.js Documentation and add a seperate endpoint to access the userinfo. This is why I will describe where it starts to differ a bit

**Step 1: Authenticate user at the Gateway**

As described in the passport.js documentation. The authentication microservice needs the following callback (The router here is already served under /auth)

```
router.get("/provider/callback", passport.authenticate("provider", {
  failureRedirect: "https://your-frontent-app.com/login",
}), (req, res) => {
  res.redirect("https://your-frontend-app.com");
});
```

When you get back to your Web-Application you will see the Session-Cookie has successfully been stored.

**Step2: Get User Info from Endpoint**

Now we need the second endpoint /auth/userinfo in our routes.

```
router.get('/userinfo', (req, res) => {
  if(!req.session) return res.status(401).send();
  if(!req.session.passport) return res.status(401).send();
  if(!req.session.passport.user) return res.status(401).send();
  return res.json(req.session.passport.user).status(200).send();
});
```

Not very pretty this block with the 3 if's but it happened to me that all of those combinations could be undefined

Now, with the session cookie stored in our browser we can call that endpoint from our front-end with the credentials (I'll use axios for that)

```
axios.get('https://your-authenticator.com/auth/userinfo', {withCredentials: true})
  .then(res => {
    //do stuff with res.data
  });
```

Now theres one more thing to note. If you want to use credentials to call that API setting the Access-Control-Allow-Origin Header to * will not work. You will have to use the specific host you'll be calling from. Also you will need to allow the Credentials in the Header. So back in your main Express app make sure you use the headers like

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://your-frontend-app.com");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Auth, Authentication, Authorization, Credentials");

  next();
});
```